# Flutter Android Platform EventChannel not stopping when back button press destroy application

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create a flutter application which uses the background service from native android plugin I am creating: a simple counter application which sends count value after every 5 seconds through EventChannel.

When I press the back button and the application is destroyed, the service is still running (that's what I want to do). But when I open the application again, the event sink is no longer sending data to new flutter view.
I think the event channel plugin is not stopping.

Answer (score 2):

When we press the back button our application gets destroyed. So EventSink (Which resides in our Native Code) can't send data to our flutter side.

You can see this message in your console:
Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.example.timestamp_saver  Response ID: 0
Here com.example.timestamp_saver is Event Channel name.

So to start listening to the events again when you open the app again after pressing back button,you need to start listening to that channel again and you can do this thing when your app state in "resumed" **OR** on some button pressed.

To do this according to the app state,follow the below steps -

1. So first implement your Stateful widget with **WidgetsBindingObserver**
2. then inside initState() method and dispose()

   ```
     @override
     void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
      }

     @override
     void dispose() {
     WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
     super.dispose();
     }
   ```
3. Now override didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) and get the current state of your application in flutter.
   **OR**
   You can start listening to Event Sink on some Refresh Buttom pressed also

   ```
   @override
   void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print('state = $state');
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed)
      {
        //start listening to the Event Sink again
        listenData();
      }
    }
   ```

Here is the listenData() method -

```
void listenData() async {
 if(Platform.isAndroid){
        var eventChannel = EventChannel("com.example.timestamp_saver");
        eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream("Just Listen").listen((event) async {
         debugPrint("Inside Listen Data");
         debugPrint(event);
      });
     }
   }
```

4. Here is my example code where I'm updating the list with timestamps in every 5 seconds.When user presses back button in that case the listener will be updated with the data emitted by EventSink so in this case I'm saving data to Database and when user will open the app again, there I'm staring to listen to the same Channel again.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:timestamp_saver/db/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:timestamp_saver/db/timestamp_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
   DBHelper _dbHelper;
   List<TimeStampModel> timeStampList;

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _dbHelper = DBHelper();
  }

   @override
   void dispose() {
     WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
     super.dispose();
   }
 

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(),
         body: Container(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: (){startServiceAndReceiveUpdatea();},
                 child: Text("Start"),
               ),
               SizedBox(height: 20,),
               RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: (){listenData();},
                 child: Text("Listen"),
               ),
               Expanded(
                   child: FutureBuilder<List<TimeStampModel>>(
                       future: _dbHelper.getTimeStampModels(),
                       builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if(snapshot.hasData)
                            {
                              timeStampList = snapshot.data;
                              return ListView.builder(
                                   itemCount: timeStampList.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                                    title: Text(timeStampList[index].timestamp),
                                  ),
                              );
                            }else if(snapshot.hasError)
                            return Center(child: Text("Error"),);
                          else
                            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                       },
                   )
               )
             ],
           ),
         )
     );
   }

  

   void startServiceAndReceiveUpdatea() async
   {
     if(Platform.isAndroid){
       var eventChannel = EventChannel("com.example.timestamp_saver");
       eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream("startService").listen((event) async {
         debugPrint("Listner called in dart");
         debugPrint(event);
         TimeStampModel timeStamp = TimeStampModel(id: null,timestamp: event);
         setState(() {

         });
    });
     }
   }

   void listenData() async
   {
     if(Platform.isAndroid){
       var eventChannel = EventChannel("com.example.timestamp_saver");
       eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream("Just Listen").listen((event) async {
         debugPrint("Inside Listen Data");
         debugPrint(event);
         TimeStampModel timeStamp = TimeStampModel(id: null,timestamp: event);
         setState(() {

         });

       });
     }
   }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.timestamp_saver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private Intent forService;
    static EventChannel.EventSink events;
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        forService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
 new EventChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor(),"com.example.timestamp_saver").setStreamHandler(new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                MainActivity.events = events;
                System.out.println("On Listen in Activity called");
                     if(arguments.equals("startService"))
                     {
                         System.out.println("if");
                         startService();
                    }else if(arguments.equals("Just Listen")){
                         System.out.println("Just Listen");
                     }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(Object arguments) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void startService(){
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            startForegroundService(forService);
        } else {
            startService(forService);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.example.timestamp_saver;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;

public class MyService extends LifecycleService {

    MutableLiveData<String> stringMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    int timerCount = 0;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    private DBManager dbManager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dbManager = new DBManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        //Creating a partial wake lock,Because if we don't create wake lock then CPU Will stop working when
        //screen will be locked,which will cause timer to work inconsistently.

        //This solution can be modified more.For example Acquire the Wake Lock when user locks the screen and release
        //it when phone gets unlock.This can be achieved using Brodcast Receiver.
        //Because Wake Lock consumes much power,so use it properly.
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)  getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl =  pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"a:waketag");
        wl.acquire();
        //stringMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"messages")
                    .setContentText("This is running in Background")
                    .setContentTitle("Flutter Background")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launch_background);

            startForeground(101,builder.build());
        }

        timerLogic();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    void timerLogic()
    {
        stringMutableLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                System.out.println("On Changed");
                if(MainActivity.events != null) {
                    dbManager.insert(s);
                    MainActivity.events.success(s);
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Event is null");
            }
        });
         

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerCount++;
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                String timerString = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                System.out.println(timerString+": "+timerCount);
                stringMutableLiveData.postValue(timerString);

            }
        },1000,5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Remember to relese wake lock
        wl.release();
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```